# flyspell, emacs and aspell seem to diverge

Tags: emacs, spelling

I'm using the following configuration for aspell in my .emacs file

```lisp
(setq ispell-program-name "/opt/local/bin/aspell")
(setq ispell-list-command "list")
(setq ispell-extra-args '("--dont-tex-check-comments"))
```

and my ~/.aspell.conf contains the following line

```
add-tex-command bibliographystyle p
```

trying this latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

emacs flyspell mode shows me plainnat as an error.

[image]

When I invoke aspell from the command line with the following command

```
aspell --dont-tex-check-comments -c ~/test.tex
```

it shows no errors. Flyspell does not seem to use aspell or the aspell config. How can I change this in such a manner that I only have to maintain one config for my spell checking needs and not have an extra config for flyspell?

Comment: When I try your test case `aspell --dont-tex-check-comments` does show "plainnat" as a spelling error. This seems correct seeing that plainnat is not a TeX comment. To ignore plainnat properly the spell checker would need to be able to differentiate between e.g. `\bibliographystyle` and `\emph` and ignore the content of the former but not the latter. If it matters I am using International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.7-20110707).

Comment: To clarify this a little more: aspell is able to ignore tex commands. This is what the "add-tex-command bibliographystyle p" line does. This line excludes the first parameter of bibliographystyle from the spellcheck. Which is does when I invoke aspell from the commandline but not during a flyspell run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flyspell uses a mode-specific function called `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` to identify areas to ignore when highlighting spelling errors. This is slightly more involved than normal customizations.

As I understand it, there are three steps. First, set the `flyspell-mode-predicate` property of `LaTeX-mode` to the name of your custom function. Second, define a function that will return `t` when point is on a word you want to ignore. Third, add a hook to `LaTeX-mode` to define `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` to use this new function whenever you enter LaTeX mode.

(The order doesn't really matter, so long as all three steps are done before you open a latex file.)

If you don't know elisp, that probably doesn't make much sense to you. Adding the following to your .emacs file and restarting Emacs should solve the problem. If you want to add additional regions to ignore, the part to play with is the `(save-excursion ... )` form.

```lisp
(put 'LaTeX-mode 'flyspell-mode-predicate 'auctex-mode-flyspell-verify)
(defun auctex-mode-flyspell-verify ()
  "Function used for `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate' in auctex mode."
  (save-excursion
    (forward-word -2)
    (not (looking-at "bibliographystyle{"))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
  (lambda () (setq flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate    
    'auctex-mode-flyspell-verify)))
```

Comment: Why are you using the (forward-word -2) here? Where is the point exactly when this function gets invoced?

Comment: (forward-word -2) backs up to the beginning of the previous word. -1 backs up to the beginning of the current word. The point is to see if the previous word is bibliography style. If it is, don't flyspell the current word. Most of the work is done behind the scenes by flyspell.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is to customize the variable `flyspell-tex-command-regexp`. The default value is

```
\(\(begin\|end\)[   ]*{\|\(cite[a-z*]*\|label\|ref\|eqref\|usepackage\|documentclass\)[     ]*\(\[[^]]*\]\)?{[^{}]*\)
```

Just append `\|bibliographystyle` (read "or bibliographystyle") as shown below:

```
\(\(begin\|end\)[   ]*{\|\(cite[a-z*]*\|label\|ref\|eqref\|usepackage\|documentclass\|bibliographystyle\)[  ]*\(\[[^]]*\]\)?{[^{}]*\)
```

You can replace `bibliographystyle` by other commands whose input you may want to ignore, e.g. `newenvironment`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a long comment than a real answer.

The behavior is even more confusing that what you describe. I used your file but added a misspelled word in a comment and a "fake" TeX command with a misspelled word as its argument

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bdfg{rwt}
\end{document}
% qwrx
```

Behavior that I saw:

- Using `aspell -c test.tex` this gives an error for "plainnat" and "rwt", but not for "qwrx". I guess my aspell doesn't need the `--dont-tex-check-comments` switch.
- Using `ispell-buffer` in emacs gives an error only for "rwt".
- Using `flyspell-buffer` in emacs gives an error for "plainnat", "rwt" and "qwrx".
- Putting point on "qwrx" or "plainnat" in emacs, and then using either `ispell-word` or `flyspell-word` gives an error.
- Putting point on either "bibliographystyle" or "bdfg" in emacs, and then using `ispell-word` gives an error, but using `flyspell-word` gives no error.
- All of the above was verified running `ispell-kill-ispell` before running the commands, to ensure that you start with a fresh ispell process. But if you, e.g., spell-check the buffer with `ispell-buffer`, "(a)ccept" "rwt" as an OK word for this session, and then run `flyspell-buffer`, flyspell will no longer complain about "rwt"

I believe that what's going on is that neither `ispell` nor `flyspell` send the entire buffer as a unit to aspell and ask it to spellcheck it [1]. Instead, the two modes go through the file one word at a time, and send each individual word to aspell. While `flyspell` does eventually call the function `ispell-word` to make the actual call to aspell [2], the logic of which words to spellcheck is *different* in `flyspell` vs `ispell`. It appears that both contain logic relevant to TeX/LaTeX, but not the same logic.

So aspell never gets a chance to apply its custom rules regarding TeX commands and their arguments, because it doesn't realize that the word "plainnat" is part of a TeX command.

I was using emacs 24.3, AUCTeX (although I don't thnk that AUCTeX does anything that really changes this behavior), aspell 3.1.20. Cygwin.

[1] This is implicit in Tyler's answer, but I think it's worth pointing it out very explicitly, because emacs' behavior here doesn't make any sense until you understand this!

[2] This probably explains the behavior in my last bullet point.

Comment: This answer is also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4674349/274967