# How to configure flyspell to ignore the content of a given environment?

Tags: emacs

When using `flyspell` in `emacs`, it can be useful to configure `flyspell` to ignore the contents of certain environments, e.g. `tikzcd` or `tikzpicture`.

For example, in the document below one would like to `flyspell` to ignore the word "asdf" inside the environment `myenv`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newenvironment{myenv}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
  asdf
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

Adding the following code to your `~/.emacs` file tells `flyspell` to ignore the content of the environments `myenv1`, `myenv2` and `myenv3`:

```lisp
(put 'LaTeX-mode 'flyspell-mode-predicate 'auctex-mode-flyspell-skip-myenv)
(defun auctex-mode-flyspell-skip-myenv ()
  (save-excursion
    (widen)
    (let ((p (point))
          (count 0))
      (not (or (and (re-search-backward "\\\\begin{\\(myenv1\\|myenv2\\|myenv3\\)}" nil t)
                    (> p (point))
                    (or (not (re-search-forward "^\\\\end{\\(myenv1\\|myenv2\\|myenv3\\)}" nil t))
                        (< p (point))))
               (eq 1 (progn (while (re-search-backward "`" (line-beginning-position) t)
                              (setq count (1+ count)))
                            (- count (* 2 (/ count 2)))))))))
  )
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (setq flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate 
                        'auctex-mode-flyspell-skip-myenv)))
```

One can append environments as necessary in lines 7 and 9 simultaneously.

Comment: This answer was adapted from http://superuser.com/questions/345084/how-to-exclude-in-flyspell-mode-and-flyspell-buffer and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61449/flyspell-emacs-and-aspell-seem-to-diverge/154535#154535

Comment: Can this solution applied for the commented blocks?